# Is Tor over wifi safe? Can people who snoop on my traffic de-anonymize my Tor traffic?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is Tor over wifi safe? Can people who snoop on my traffic de-anonymize my Tor traffic (assuming I use Tor Browser)?

Answer (score -1):

WiFi is just a basic network level for Tor in your case/question, so it does not differ from wired network connection in matters of anti-snooping security: all the snooper will see will be Tor encrypted traffic. Yes, as a wired one too, it has it's weakneses, but Tor and Tor Browser are working completely independent of network packet transmission layer.

Comment: Wireless clearly does differ from wired connections "in matters of anti-snooping security"?

Comment: unless you're using a weak WiFi connection security or just doing a plain/direct requests - Tor from the TBB will operate as normal, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Tor is fine but there is a clear difference between wired and wireless in terms of requirements to snoop. Saying they do not differ is misleading.

Comment: @canonizingironize please read the *whole* answer, not a cherrypick phrase. Thanks!

Comment: I did. First of all the statement is incorrect, second of all as you later point out it's not relevant to Tor because any snooper would only see already encrypted Tor traffic. You might be better to just remove the statement entirely since it doesn't bring any value to the answer.

Comment: @canonizingironize clarified my first statement, but IMHO if I'm answering the particular question or reviewing a specific case - the statements are applied to this *very specific situation*, not in general scope.